# Chrome keeps forgetting my sessions on every reboot on Loki

Tags: release-loki, google-chrome

I'm running the latest version of chrome and every time I reboot elementary, I'm having to re-login to Chrome (via the settings menu).

[image]

Other websites I've signed into, like Fb, SO etc also keep logging me out. Cookies are enabled in Chrome.

Why does this keep happening and how can I avoid it?

**Edit:** thought the problem was related to autologin and the key ring not getting unlocked in time but this is not the issue. Sometimes the issue happens even when the computer is locked/idle for a while and I come back to Chrome. This is the message displayed in Chrome. My account is fine, and this never happens on Windows.

**Edit 2:** The issue has been [reported here](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/7BF8U4o_u_o;context-place=forum/chrome/categories). The reply by Igor Bukin  seems to be a possible fix for this issue, but cannot be done on elementary as I'm unable to add a Google account in `Settings>Online Accounts`.

[image]

**Edit 3:** This issue has cleared itself over time, without needing a particular fix. If the issue resurfaces I will be updating this question.

Comment: How did you install Chrome?

Comment: Downloaded from their official site (selected Ubuntu version) and installed the .deb file with dpkg -i

Comment: Having the same issue here, it's kind of annoying

Comment: Having the same problem here... Also downloaded from google website.

Comment: Having same issues, and it is annoying. Switched to **chromium** and it works ok.

Comment: I have chrome, and it's work fine for me .... Do you use passphrase ? I mean in Settings > Advanced Synchronize Parameters > Encryption Options (not sure, I translated menu name). I uploaded an screenshot to show you what I'm talking about : http://nsa38.casimages.com/img/2016/12/12/161212054701305201.png

Comment: @Shining I know I didn't change anything there.. Also, the issue seems to have solved itself over time, without needing a fix.